# How to set a property of a function which is defined as a property, during declaration

Tags: javascript, codemirror

JSFiddle in [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5Lwxvvpw/), this is a JavaScript and/or [CodeMirror](https://codemirror.net/) question.

In the below snippet, `hint` function is defined as a property in `hintOptions` object.

Is there a possibility to set a property of that function, without defining it outside the code block?

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(myTextarea, {
    hintOptions: {
        hint: function(cm, callback, options) {
            return {
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I tried with anonymous function, as in:

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(myTextarea, {
    hintOptions: {
        hint: (function(cm, callback, options) {
            return {
            }
        })({
            async: true
        })
    }
});
```

but it seems to be a syntax error, since the JavaScript doesn't work at all.

As CodeMirror [docs](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html) mention:

> hint: function
>
> A hinting function, as specified above. It is possible to set the `async` property on a hinting function to true, in which case it will be called with arguments (cm, callback, ?options)

To check if `async` is correctly set:

1. Open the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5Lwxvvpw/)
2. Click on the 'class code'
3. Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>
4. The `log` textarea should have not `undefined`

Comment: Not really clear what your objective is or what higher level problem you are trying to solve

Comment: I don't know if it is possible to configure that property with JavaScript in this scenario (so the code is compact), or I have to remove the function away from the declaration as a property.  Or in other words, how best to define that `async` property.

Comment: should be `hint: async function...`

Comment: It doesn't work, please check updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5Lwxvvpw/1/)

Comment: @charlietfl: please check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/sqkxy3a1/)

Comment: Am confused myself about what the docs are referring to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An IIFE in the object initialiser to create a function with an `async` property seems to work:

```js
let testObj = {
    hintOptions: {
        hint:   (function () {
            let hint = function(cm, callback, options) {
                 log(options);
                 return {
                     from: cm.getDoc().getCursor(),
                     to: cm.getaDoc().getCursor(),
                     list: ['foo', 'bar']
                 }
             }
             hint.async = true;
             return hint
        })()
    }
};

console.log("hint.async: " + testObj.hintOptions.hint.async);
```

I managed to get "[object Object]" in the fiddle following the post instructions  but don't know it that is the expected result.

Comment: Indeed, as you get other than `undefined`, then it is what is needed, thanks.